# How to terminate ruby unit test with "Pass" or success status

Tags: ruby, testunit

First of all thank you very much for reading this question.

I am using Ruby-1.8.7 and Webdriver to connect to FF browser. I am testing our product functionality. There is a form and  I am giving wrong input and expecting error message.  This is 5 steps (pages) process and when I click on  next button I may get error based on my input on that particular page. Error comes only when there is wrong input and I click on next button. If I get expected error message, I should mark test as pass.  Simple example is if I enter too long description in the Description field, system will throw error message "Description too long."

Problem here is While my testing whenever I get this kind of expected error, I want to terminate Ruby unit test with Pass/Success and execute new test.

I tried different way but can not set the test as pass/success. 
Sample code.

```
def enterdata()

    ...
    click_next_and_check_for_error_message(timeout,expected_message)
    set_file_server_settings(args)
    click_next_and_check_for_error_message(timeout,expected_message)
    set_select_filters(args)
    click_next_and_check_for_error_message(timeout,expected_message)
    set_registration_scope(args)
    click_next_and_check_for_error_message(timeout,expected_message)
    set_schedule_scan(args)
    click_next_and_check_for_error_message(timeout,expected_message)
end

def click_next_and_check_for_error_message(...)

    ...

    if !message.empty?      
        print "\nExpected is #{exp_msg}"
        print "\nActual is #{message}"
        if (exp_msg == message)
        #if assert_equal( exp_msg, message, "Expected message #{exp_msg} did not come" )        
        print "\n*** MATACHED ***\n"
        raise TestPassed
    else
        raise ApplianceFailure, message
    end      
end
```

With both exo_msg and message are same, test should be terminated with success as I was expecting it.

Please guide me.

Test::Unit

Comment: Don't know about Test::Unit, but in rspec there's a `expect { some code }.to raise_error(MySpecificError)`

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev  Thanks for editing formatting this code